# ImportError: cannot import name 'to_categorical' from 'keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-import

I have just got below error from an import that use to work fine few hours ago going downward.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-4c52b67c20bf> in <module>()
      1 import keras
----> 2 from keras.utils import to_categorical

ImportError: cannot import name 'to_categorical' from 'keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is Keras busy with Update to have this method deprecated?

[image]

Answer (score 79):

**use this**

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```

**instead of**

<strike>from keras.utils import to_categorical</strike>

Comment: can you add some information, or any link from documentation regarding this change. The author of Keras uses *from keras.utils import to_categorical* in his book.

Comment: ```from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical``` it is works for me

Comment: @shy-tan it's probably because of the migration from TensorFlow 1.x. to 2.x. Keras got bundled into tensorflow. your book most likely is using TensorFlow 1